# How do you test the significance of regression estimated parameters (fitting data)?

Tags: python, scipy, sklearn-pandas, non-linear-regression, p-value

I made a regression model that tries to fit my data (x: year, y: number of cars). And now I feel frustrated. How to assess if the estimated parameters (p = 0.0001695867, q = 0.349592505) are significant? How to perform some statistical tests (estimate p-values for both p and q, t-statistics) to test the significance of p and q. And maybe an F-test of overall significance in regression analysis. For some reason, I'm not interested in finding confidence intervals for p and q. But p-values or t-statistics or whatever are of more interest for me to calculate. So that

> Ho : p statistically insignificant H1 : p statistically significant. Same for q.

And an F-test:

> Ho: p & q = 0 at the same time. H1: either p or q doesn't equal 0

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_excel('fitting_data.xlsx', sheet_name="bevshyb cars (2)", index_col=None, dtype={'Name': str, 'Value': float})
import numpy as np
#regression function
def fit(t,p,q):
    return 22500000*(((p*p*p+2*p*p*q+p*q*q)*np.exp(-p*t-q*t))/(((p+q*np.exp(-p*t-q*t))*(p+q*np.exp(-p*t-q*t)))))
#initial values
g = [0.000001,0.000001]
import scipy.optimize
t = x['t'].values
carsfact = x['BEVSHYB'].values
c, cov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fit,t,carsfact,g)
print(round(c[0],10))
print(round(c[1],10))
```

Estimated parameters: p & q respectively == 0.0001695867, 0.349592505

```
import sklearn.metrics 
print('R^2: ',sklearn.metrics.r2_score(x['BEVSHYB'],y))
print('explained_variance_score: ', sklearn.metrics.explained_variance_score(x['BEVSHYB'], y))
```

Assessing goodness-of-fit in the regression model:
R^2:  0.9143477744061798
explained_variance_score:  0.9168457427666166

Will appreciate any help)))

Answer (score 0):

Please, consult the answer to the question posted in this link: it shows one way of assessing the significance of the optimized parameters:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362520/how-to-know-if-a-parameter-is-statistically-significant-in-a-curve-fit-estimat

Here's the sample code featured over there; note the usage of scipy.stats:

````
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import scipy.odr
import scipy.stats

x = np.array([5.357, 5.797, 5.936, 6.161, 6.697, 6.731, 6.775, 8.442, 9.861])
y = np.array([0.376, 0.874, 1.049, 1.327, 2.054, 2.077, 2.138, 4.744, 7.104])

def f(x,b0,b1):
    return b0 + (b1 * x)


def f_wrapper_for_odr(beta, x): # parameter order for odr
    return f(x, *beta)

parameters, cov= curve_fit(f, x, y)

model = scipy.odr.odrpack.Model(f_wrapper_for_odr)
data = scipy.odr.odrpack.Data(x,y)
myodr = scipy.odr.odrpack.ODR(data, model, beta0=parameters,  maxit=0)
myodr.set_job(fit_type=2)
parameterStatistics = myodr.run()
df_e = len(x) - len(parameters) # degrees of freedom, error
cov_beta = parameterStatistics.cov_beta # parameter covariance matrix from ODR
sd_beta = parameterStatistics.sd_beta * parameterStatistics.sd_beta
ci = []
t_df = scipy.stats.t.ppf(0.975, df_e)
ci = []
for i in range(len(parameters)):
    ci.append([parameters[i] - t_df * parameterStatistics.sd_beta[i], parameters[i] + t_df * parameterStatistics.sd_beta[i]])

tstat_beta = parameters / parameterStatistics.sd_beta # coeff t-statistics
pstat_beta = (1.0 - scipy.stats.t.cdf(np.abs(tstat_beta), df_e)) * 2.0    # coef. p-values

for i in range(len(parameters)):
    print('parameter:', parameters[i])
    print('   conf interval:', ci[i][0], ci[i][1])
    print('   tstat:', tstat_beta[i])
    print('   pstat:', pstat_beta[i])
    print()
```
````

Comment: I got one silly question
is this line of code t_df = scipy.stats.t.ppf(0.975, df_e) means 97.5% conf interval, so if I change this to 0.95 will it work?

Comment: With alpha = 0.05, the value of t for a 2-tailed t-test has to be computed using the ppf method with the probability of 0.0975 = 1 - 0.05/2 as the first parameter.

Comment: Oh thanks so that's already 95% conf interval

Comment: You are very welcome. Please, consider selecting my answer in case it was helpful to you.